# SetupDiGetClassDevs causing error on XP

Tags: wpf, windows-xp, setupapi

I have a Win32 application that is invoked by another WPF application. In the Win32 tray application I am registering for USB Device notifications. In this I use the API call to SetupDiGetClassDevs So that I can look for any connected devices.

On XP the WIN32 application crashes with error:
"The procedure entry point RegOpenKeyExW could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNAL32.dll"

on win7 and win8 the API call functions properly. The Application is build on Win7 VS2010.

Is there an issue with Calling SetupDIGetClassDevs on XP sp3?

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I'm not sure I see the direct link between SetupDiGetClassDevs() and RegOpenKeyExW().  However, this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724897%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) shows that RegOpenKeyEx() is in Advapi32.dll not Kernel32.dll.  Could this be the source of your angst?